# Alternative of camel Java config for configuring routes using camel in spring 6

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, spring-framework-beans

I’m using camel-spring-javaconfig to configure camel routes in spring 5 application. Now I’m migrating to spring 6 and found that camel-spring-javaconfig is deprecated.

So I want to know how to configure camel routes with out using camel-spring-Javaconfig in spring 6 applications

Comment: Can you switch to Spring Boot? The Camel developers [recommend Spring Boot as the replacement for camel-spring-javaconfig](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@camel.apache.org/msg65203.html).

Comment: @ChinHuang does camel support spring boot 3

Comment: [Apache Camel 4](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2023/01/camel4roadmap/) will support Spring Boot 3.

Comment: @ChinHuang im facing the below error while using camel-spring-javaconfig:3.14.7 along with spring 6 while deploying in tomcat 10.

Comment: CamelSpringJavaconfigInitializationException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[http://0.0.0.0:0000/?bridgeEndpoint=true&urlRewrite=#urlRewriter&httpClientConfigurer=clientConfigurer] <<< in route: Route(route1)[From[servlet://?matchOnUriPrefix=true&httpBind... because of No endpoint could be found for: http://0.0.0.0:0000/?bridgeEndpoint=true&urlRewrite=#urlRewriter&httpClientConfigurer=clientConfigurer, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.

Comment: @ChinHuang i havent faced this issue while using spring 5 and camel-spring-javaconfig:3.7